# invalid parameter in posting offer to facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have problem with posting offer to page (which I am admin) via facebook api. It'is work, when I post feed to this page, but not for offers. This always return me FacebookSDKException with message : Invalid parameter. I use PHP (Laravel framework), but I think it does not matter on the language I use. I use this code:

```
try {
        $response = $fb->post('/'  . $page_id . '/offers' , $offerData, (string) $request->access_token
                );
    } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$e->getMessage(),
            ], 200);
    }
```

where my "$request->access_token" is page access token. And in my "$offerData" I have this fields:

```
$offerData =[
        'claim_limit'=>8,
        'expiration_time'=>\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(10)->toDateTimeString(),
        'message'=>"bbb",
        'title'=>"ascvc",
        'coupon_required'=>false,
        'image_url'=>'...',
        'published'=>true,
        'reminder_time'=>\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(5)->toDateTimeString(),
       // 'scheduled_publish_time'=>5
    ];
```

I also try do this by curl (not by first code) and by curl it returns similar error message.

```
"{"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":1528104,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Check Your Admin Permission Level","error_user_msg":"Only some admins of your Page are able to create and edit offers. Talk to the person responsible for your Page about your admin permission level.","fbtrace_id":"..."}}"
```

It looks that there is problem with permissions but at login to facebook I set this permissions:

```
['manage_pages', 'pages_show_list', 'email',
        'user_hometown', 'publish_actions', 'user_photos', 'publish_pages']
```

I have no idea where is problem. I must to tell you that feeds on same page works fine, but not offers. Can you help me, please?

Comment: This is not about permissions you ask from the user to grant to your app, but what level of admin permissions the person has assigned in the page settings.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the newer /nativeoffers endpoint; that should be a cleaner path through this one.

https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/08/30/offer-ads-apis/